# Understanding custom JQuery event and how to modify it sligthly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted and event emitter on an input that had a slightly delay (cooldown) when entering input, say 1 second, so typing a word would trigger it multiple times, but only 1 second after the last key stroke

I found this code

```
  $.fn.changeOrDelayedKey = function(fn, iKeyDelay, sKeyEvent) {
    var iTimeoutId,
        oEventData;

    // second signature used, update the variables
    if (!$.isFunction(fn)) {
        oEventData = arguments[0];
        fn = arguments[1];
        iKeyDelay = arguments[2];
        sKeyEvent = arguments[3];
    }

    if (!iKeyDelay || 0 > iKeyDelay) {
        iKeyDelay = 500;
    }

    if (!sKeyEvent || !this[sKeyEvent]) {
        sKeyEvent = 'keydown';
    }

    // non-delayed event callback, should clear any timeouts, then
    // call the original callback function
    function fnExecCallback() {
        clearTimeout(iTimeoutId);
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // delayed event callback, should call the non-delayed callback
    // after a short interval
    function fnDelayCallback() {
        var that = this,
            args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(iTimeoutId);
        iTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            fnExecCallback.apply(that, args);
        }, iKeyDelay);
    }

    if (oEventData) {
        this.change(oEventData, fnExecCallback);
        this[sKeyEvent](oEventData, fnDelayCallback);
    }
    else {
        this.change(fnExecCallback);
        this[sKeyEvent](fnDelayCallback);
    }

    return this;
  };
```

Which kind of does this, but it also triggers on `change`, which means that if i write something without moving moving the focus after say, 5 seconds, then when i finally, the event fires again, which it shouldnt. So I only want the event to happen on the `keyup` event.

If anyone could explain how the method work, and how I could modify it to fit my usecase it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your usage, you can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` for this:

```js
$(function() {
    var timeOut = 0;
    $("#test")
        .keyup(function() {
        // cancel looking, the user typed another character
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        // set a timeout, when user doesn't type another key
        // within half a second the function is called
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
   stopptedTyping();
  }, 500); // change time as needed
    });

});

function stopptedTyping(){
  alert('user stopped typing');  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```